# Setting up a RAID 1 in Funtoo

Tags: linux, mount, disk, raid1, funtoo

## In short

Following the guide [How to Set Up a RAID 1 Under GNU/Linux](http://blog.infertux.com/2012/03/29/how-to-set-up-a-raid-1-under-gnu-slash-linux/), I have setup  a RAID 1. Checking the RAID Array for validity in various ways, appeared to be normal.

However, after rebooting the system, the RAID Array was not working. The partition in question was not mounted as instructed in `/etc/fstab`. Assembling the Array manually worked and no data has been lost.

Newly added internal/external disks, which lead to a change of the disk device names (such as a disk being "renamed" from `sdd` to `sde` by the system), lead me to accept that it was a problem related with this name-changing fact. This is irrelevant, however, as RAID Arrays are (also) built by using unique UUIDs.

The actual question is *why does the Array fail to assemble during the boot process?* Or else, *what is the boot-script of Funtoo, the operating system under which all of plot takes place, doing regarding the `mdadm -assemble` process?*

## The long story

Following the above referenced step by step guide, I have set up a RAID 1 under Funtoo. Checking the RAID 1 Array for validity was done in several ways, mostly using functionalities of the `mdadm` tool itself.

Specifically, the Array's details were retrieved by using the `mdadm` tool with the `-D` flag. The disks that pertain to the Array were examined by using the `-E` flag. The respective configuration file `mdadm.conf` can be simply read for if it contains the correct instruction (i.e which md device, what is its UUID and more). Finally, watching the file `/proc/mdadm` was important to ensure that both disks were active and "synced".

Below follow even more detailed information about the confronted situation.

```
mdadm -D /dev/md0

/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Jul 18 00:25:05 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1953382208 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953382208 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Jul 18 10:33:37 2013
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : Resilience:0  (local to host Resilience)
           UUID : 73bf29ca:89bff887:79a26531:b9733d7a
         Events : 6455

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       2       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
```

From the command history, I did the following

```
# trying to follow the guide -- various tests...
      ...
      979  18.Jul.13 [ 00:09:07 ] mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdd1
      980  18.Jul.13 [ 00:09:17 ] mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-disks=2 missing /dev/sdd1
      990  18.Jul.13 [ 00:15:58 ] mdadm --examine --scan

# creating/checking the configuration file

      992  18.Jul.13 [ 00:16:17 ] cat /etc/mdadm.conf 
      993  18.Jul.13 [ 00:16:33 ] mdadm --examine --scan | tee /etc/mdadm.conf
      994  18.Jul.13 [ 00:16:35 ] cat /etc/mdadm.conf 

# after some faulty attempts, finally it goes

      997  18.Jul.13 [ 00:24:45 ] mdadm --stop /dev/md0
      998  18.Jul.13 [ 00:24:54 ] mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdd1
      999  18.Jul.13 [ 00:25:04 ] mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-disks=2 missing /dev/sdd1
     1005  18.Jul.13 [ 00:26:39 ] mdadm --examine --scan | sudo tee /etc/mdadm.conf
     1046  18.Jul.13 [ 03:42:57 ] mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1
```

The configuration file `/etc/mdadm.conf` reads:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=73bf29ca:89bff887:79a26531:b9733d7a name=Resilience:0
```

All works fine as can be seen from `/proc/mdadm`:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid1] [raid0] [raid10] [linear] [multipath] 
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[2] sdd1[1]
      1953382208 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Here after, the disks were synced, access was fine. Shutting down the system, adding another disk, external (via USB) or internal, and restarting the system, caused the RAID1 to stop working!  The reason is, if I am not wrong, the change of disk device numbers.

In this example, the former `sdd1` became `sde1` while `sdd1` was reserved by a "new" internal disk or an external USB HDD attached before starting the system and instructed to be automatically mounted.

It was very easy to "recover" the "failed" ARRAY by removing all other disks, stopping the Array and re-assembling it. Some of the commands issued while trying and, finally, successfully getting back the ARRAY were:

```
# booting and unsuccessfully trying to add the "missing" disk

     1091  18.Jul.13 [ 10:22:53 ] mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1
     1092  18.Jul.13 [ 10:28:26 ] mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --scan
     1093  18.Jul.13 [ 10:28:39 ] mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --scan --force
     1095  18.Jul.13 [ 10:30:36 ] mdadm --detail /dev/md0

# reading about `mdadm`, trying to "stop", incomplete command though

     1096  18.Jul.13 [ 10:30:45 ] mdadm stop
     1097  18.Jul.13 [ 10:31:12 ] mdadm --examine /dev/sdd
     1098  18.Jul.13 [ 10:31:16 ] mdadm --examine /dev/sdd1
     1099  18.Jul.13 [ 10:31:20 ] mdadm --examine /dev/sdc
     1100  18.Jul.13 [ 10:31:21 ] mdadm --examine /dev/sdc1

# reading again, stop it -- the right way

     1101  18.Jul.13 [ 10:33:19 ] mdadm --stop /dev/md0

# assemble & check

     1102  18.Jul.13 [ 10:33:25 ] mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --scan
     1111  18.Jul.13 [ 10:34:17 ] mdadm --examine /dev/sd[cd]1

# does the Array have a UUID?

     1112  18.Jul.13 [ 10:37:36 ] UUID=$(mdadm -E /dev/sdd1|perl -ne '/Array UUID : (\S+)/ and print $1')

# below, learning how to report on the Array

     1115  18.Jul.13 [ 10:42:26 ] mdadm -D /dev/md0
     1116  18.Jul.13 [ 10:45:08 ] mdadm --examine /dev/sd[cd]1 >> raid.status
     1197  18.Jul.13 [ 13:16:59 ] mdadm --detail /dev/md0
     1198  18.Jul.13 [ 13:17:29 ] mdadm --examine /dev/sd[cd]1
     1199  18.Jul.13 [ 13:17:41 ] mdadm --help
     1200  18.Jul.13 [ 13:18:41 ] mdadm --monitor /dev/md0
     1201  18.Jul.13 [ 13:18:53 ] mdadm --misc /dev/md0
```

However, I would expect this not to happen, and be able to play safe as with the rest of disks/partitions when mounting is based on UUIDs and/or LABELs.

The corresponding entry in `/etc/fstab` reads (**note**, I skipped the options `nosuid,nodev`)

```
/dev/md0        geo     xfs     defaults        0 2
```

Details for `sdc1`, output from `mdadm -E /dev/sdc1`

```
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 73bf29ca:89bff887:79a26531:b9733d7a
           Name : Resilience:0  (local to host Resilience)
  Creation Time : Thu Jul 18 00:25:05 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953382208 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906764416 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5552ba2d:8d79c88f:c995d052:cef0aa03

    Update Time : Fri Jul 19 11:14:19 2013
       Checksum : 385183dd - correct
         Events : 6455


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

**Details for the partitions in question**

Details for `sdd1`, output from `mdadm -E /dev/sdd1`

```
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 73bf29ca:89bff887:79a26531:b9733d7a
           Name : Resilience:0  (local to host Resilience)
  Creation Time : Thu Jul 18 00:25:05 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953382208 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906764416 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 076acfd8:af184e75:f83ce3ae:8e778ba0

    Update Time : Fri Jul 19 11:14:19 2013
       Checksum : c1df68a0 - correct
         Events : 6455


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

After adding, again, a "new" internal disk, and rebooting, I experience the same problem.

`mdadm -E /dev/sdd1` reports

```
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdd1.
```

while `mdadm -E /dev/sde1`

```
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 73bf29ca:89bff887:79a26531:b9733d7a
           Name : Resilience:0  (local to host Resilience)
  Creation Time : Thu Jul 18 00:25:05 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953382208 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906764416 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 076acfd8:af184e75:f83ce3ae:8e778ba0

    Update Time : Fri Jul 19 11:34:47 2013
       Checksum : c1df6d6c - correct
         Events : 6455


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

and `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`

```
mdadm: md device /dev/md0 does not appear to be active.
```

while `cat /proc/mdstat` reads

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid1] [raid0] [raid10] [linear] [multipath] 
md0 : inactive sde1[1](S)
      1953382400 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

Note, as per *Gilles'* observation, at this point the reported blocks (1953382400) do not match the ones reported for the `Array Size : 1953382208`, as can be seen above (or below).  Obviously, something went wrong here.

The (partial) output of `mdadm -Evvvvs` is

```
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 73bf29ca:89bff887:79a26531:b9733d7a
           Name : Resilience:0  (local to host Resilience)
  Creation Time : Thu Jul 18 00:25:05 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953382208 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906764416 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 076acfd8:af184e75:f83ce3ae:8e778ba0

    Update Time : Fri Jul 19 11:34:47 2013
       Checksum : c1df6d6c - correct
         Events : 6455


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sde:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907026944 sectors at         2048 (type fd)

/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 73bf29ca:89bff887:79a26531:b9733d7a
           Name : Resilience:0  (local to host Resilience)
  Creation Time : Thu Jul 18 00:25:05 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 1953382208 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906764416 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5552ba2d:8d79c88f:c995d052:cef0aa03

    Update Time : Fri Jul 19 11:34:47 2013
       Checksum : 385188a9 - correct
         Events : 6455


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907026944 sectors at         2048 (type fd)
```

Checking with `fdisk -l`, the previous <strike>`sdc` and</strike> `sdd` disk<strike>s</strike>, <strike>are</strike>is now <strike>`sdb` and</strike> `sde` (recognise the<strike>m</strike> disks from the size among the rest of the drives). It seems that "it" is still looking at/for <strike>`sdc1`</strike>`sdd1`?

Following suggestions found in the comment section, I added more details.

As per *derobert's* suggestion in the comments, the ARRAY stopped and re-assembled successfully:

```
# stop it!
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: stopped /dev/md0

# re-assemble -- looks good!
mdadm --assemble -v --scan

mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md/0
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdf1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdf
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda6
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda5
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda4
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda3
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sde1 is identified as a member of /dev/md/0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md/0, slot 0.
mdadm: added /dev/sde1 to /dev/md/0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdc1 to /dev/md/0 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md/0 has been started with 2 drives.

# double-check
mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 name=Resilience:0 UUID=73bf29ca:89bff887:79a26531:b9733d7a
```

**New question**, how is this to be fixed <strike>that without loosing data</strike>? As per the discussion and recommendations in the comments, it is related with the boot process?  <strike>Permissions to the mount point in question perhaps?</strike>

`mdadm` was not registered as a boot service. Adding it and rebooting, did not fix the issue though.  A few more, probably interesting, details from `dmesg` on where it fails:

```
[   25.356947] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[   25.356952] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[   25.356955] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
[   25.383630] md: raid1 personality registered for level 1
[   25.677100] md: raid0 personality registered for level 0
[   26.134282] md: raid10 personality registered for level 10
[   26.257855] md: linear personality registered for level -1
[   26.382152] md: multipath personality registered for level -4
[   41.986222] md: bind<sde1>
[   44.274346] XFS (md0): SB buffer read failed
[   55.028598] ata7: sas eh calling libata cmd error handler
[   55.028615] ata7.00: cmd ef/05:fe:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0
[   55.046186] ata7: sas eh calling libata cmd error handler
[   55.046209] ata7.00: cmd ef/c2:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0
[   55.278378] ata8: sas eh calling libata cmd error handler
[   55.278406] ata8.00: cmd ef/05:fe:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0
[   55.349235] ata8: sas eh calling libata cmd error handler
[   55.349290] ata8.00: cmd ef/c2:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0
[  105.854112] XFS (md0): SB buffer read failed
```

<strike>Further checking the XFS partition in question `sde1`</strike>

```
xfs_check /dev/sde1
xfs_check: /dev/sde1 is not a valid XFS filesystem (unexpected SB magic number 0x00000000)
xfs_check: WARNING - filesystem uses v1 dirs,limited functionality provided.
xfs_check: read failed: Invalid argument
cache_node_purge: refcount was 1, not zero (node=0x22a64a0)
xfs_check: cannot read root inode (22)
bad superblock magic number 0, giving up
```

It turns out that the XFS partition in question is not healthy.

An XFS filesystem, although not impossible, is likely not the root of the problem here. Partitions that are part of an RAID Array, are according to Gilles' comment, *not an XFS filesystem! The filesystem starts at an offset, there's a RAID header first.*

## Question(s)

**In the beginning**

- Is it possible to "lock" the RAID 1 Array to only work with specific disks/partitions independently from disk device names?
- Would it be, for example, sufficient to use the Array's UUID in `/etc/fstab` so as to be immune against changes of the disk device names?

**After re-searching the problem**

- At what stage of Funtoo's boot process is the assembmel of the RAID Array attempted? How exactly?  Where can it be modified/adjusted?

Comment: `/etc/fstab` isn't considered when assembling the array. Your partition type code should be 0xDA. And please post `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`. Also, when is the assembly being attempted, during initramfs or after?

Comment: The question is odd. By default, `mdadm` has no problem what so ever with changing device names, added disks. Locking their names (which is not feasible) won't fix anything. It identifies them by metadata which is stored on each RAID member. Something else must have gone wrong for you.

Comment: @derobert Updated the question with the content of `/etc/mdadm.conf` (I work under Funtoo). About pre- or post-_initramfs_, of course (I say, becasues I have no idea about the importance of "when") after.

Comment: @frostschutz How so? If you have a RAID 1 which includes `sdd1` and `sde1`, and, suddenly `sdd1` becomes `sdf1` simply because the system (hardware, BIOS) re-sorted the names after attaching a new disk, isn't that a problem? I really have no idea about RAID.  Could you please, if you want, explain in short, or else point to a specific documentation shedding light on this particular aspect?

Comment: @derobert Ehm... which assembly are you referring to? Re-assembling the (existing) Array or something else?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris part of the system boot process is calling `mdadm --assemble`. That's the assembly I'm referring to.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what broke, without guessing? Mdraid doesn't use device names, it uses signatures to assemble the array. In other words, `/dev/md0` is not built from `sdc1` and `sdd1`, it's built from `73bf29ca:89bff887:79a26531:b9733d7a`. The number `/dev/md0` is also stable since it comes from `/etc/mdadm.conf`. However, your bootloader may have been affected.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris It sounds like you can boot the system with the extra disk attached, and the array doesn't come up. I'd suggest looking at the boot messages and seeing what is different. Also, you can try (without removing the extra disk) `mdadm --stop /dev/md0` followed by `mdadm --assemble -v --scan`. If that puts your array together, then `mdadm` itself is working, we have to figure out why your OS's boot scripts aren't. If that doesn't put your array together, can we get that output?

Comment: @Gilles As I described in the "question", shutting down, attaching a new disk (internal) and/or an external -- this is what I did only without touching the RAID configuration or whatsoever -- "resulted" in the one partition being mirrored (RAID 1) not to be accessible. This is what I observed, of course. All this might be "guessing" since I don't know what really happened. I checked the "status", i.e. instructing `mdadm --examine` for the partitions in question and the output was something erroneous, don't remember exactly what. I still have my history log, will update the question.

Comment: @Gilles @derobert The mirrored partition, as the device names `sdc`, `sdd` imply (for most cases out there, my guess it is :-)), are data-only. I am hesitant to attach other disks before booting the machine so as to not loose the Array again! Based on what you explain about `/dev/md0` being built from the UUID, obviously, attaching new disk(s) pre-booting, is irrelevant and I shouldn't worry. I have 1.5TB of data inside which I cannot loose. So, I'd like to do things I only understand and anything required to understand the problem.

Comment: @Gilles @derobert I updated the "question": added some stuff from the command history. One thing I missed, following the "guide", were the `nosuid,nodev` bit for the mounting instruction in `fstab`. These missing are not the problem, right?

Comment: @Gilles @derobert Well, I couldn't wait but to try. It happened again. Booted, the partition in question is not mounted and `mdadm -E /dev/sdd1` reports `mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdd1.`. What's next?

Comment: Apologies for the many updates. I just add new stuff/details that are, I think, related with the problem. I am not doing any further changes. Simply issuing `mount -a` complains like `mount: /dev/md0: can't read superblock`.

Comment: @Gilles, derobert, I am re-reading all of your helpful comments. You are probably both on the right track. I will update, yet another time, my question as I tried derobert's suggestion to stop and re-assemble the array. It works. So, it's Funtoo's boot script then?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Indeed, it looks like the array is being assembled incorrectly. In the non-working state, `mdstat -E /dev/sde1` looks correct but `/proc/mdstat` reports 1953382400 blocks instead of 1953382208. Do you have a way of seeing what `mdadm` command is run to assemble it? Is this being done from an initrd or initramfs, or after the root partition is active?

Comment: @Gilles I think I found it: `rc-status boot | grep md` gives nothing :-! So, `rc-update add mdadm boot` should be correct to do (see also Gentoo's wiki page on [RAID/Software](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/RAID/Software)). Apologies for my ignorance. I will simply try it to see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: @Gilles Nope, the same issue again. `mdadm` added and running as a boot service. This isn't enough/the problem.

Comment: @Gilles @derobert I have added some details extracted from `dmesg`. What other logs can/should I look into?

Comment: Seems it is an _XFS bad magic number_ error! In case `xfs_repair -n` wont suggest a solution, can I simply simulate as if the disk has failed and let it resync? I don't expect a hardware error since the disks are brand new. Well, one can never know of course.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Please do *not* attempt to run xfs_repair (or anything else, really) on the underlying disks. Thankfully it errored out... You want to run that on the RAID device instead (`/dev/md0` or `/dev/md/0`, whichever it is on your system). The errors you saw in the log were because the array wasn't assembled correctly, so md refused access (to protect your data). Your array appears to be find (as long as xfs_repair did nothing), its just the system boot scripts. That should mean your data is safe. But you should have back ups, of course! RAID will not protect from accidental `rm -Rf`

Comment: Boot goes in the order 1. Identify disks, create device files for them (/dev/sdX). 2. Assemble arrays, create device files for them (/dev/md0). 3. Mount filesystems. (2) is what is failing, so it'd be very unlikely for a permission issue on the mountpoint to be responsible (as that wouldn't hit until 3). Plus, this is all done as root, so e.g., SELinux, there aren't going to be permission problems.

Comment: `/dev/sde1` is not an XFS fileysystem! The filesystem starts at an offset, there's a RAID header first. TO access a RAID volume with a 1.1 or 1.2 signature level, you need to go through mdraid.

Comment: @derobert I did only try `xfs_repair -n` which should be only reading stuff and not touching at all. Anyway, I stopped it. Alright, the data is still there :-). Manually re-assembling and mounting the `/md/0` "partition" at `/geo` works fine, as it did before. I couldn't keep fingers away so I removed and re-added the `sde1` partition to the array, re-assemble using the `--update=resync` option. Do I understand it **wrongly** that, in this case, `resync` will sync (from the healthy disk, that is `sdc1`) to the "newly' added disk (well, `sde1`) everything, **including** _superblock_ info?

Comment: No, I don't have an extra Back Up of everything. As soon as the resync completes, I'll backup **everything** in another available disk.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I've never used the --update=resync option... Not entirely sure what it does, but `iostat -kx 10` will tell you which disk is reading and which is writing.

Comment: @derobert Excellent advice/tool: `sdc` is reading, `sde` is writing. There is some (old! but) "similar" discussion at storageforum.net [RAID Superblock disappeared from one of my disks after crash. Fix?](http://www.storageforum.net/forum/showthread.php/5890-RAID-Superblock-disappeared-from-one-of-my-disks-after-crash-Fix?s=ff5a0782ea34ac5a379296ae7cdc49a0&p=86815&viewfull=1#post86815). But maybe I am still confused -- how to proceed in seeing what happens at boot-ing? Which logs should I consult?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris It may be happening in initramfs before any filesystems are mounted, in which case there may well be no log. You'd have to watch the messages as they scroll by on the console. You could try capturing them with a camera phone (see if you can read them if you record the boot in video mode). Alternatively, set up a serial or network console to capture them. You could also try updating your initramfs, maybe it has an old idea of the array? (`update-initramfs -u`)

Comment: @derobert Thank you for your patiance and support. On the way up, I do read some nice red-colored _Some local filesystems failed to mount_ or similar message. On the way down, `fcron` fails to stop properly before halting the system (but this is probably irrelevant). I will need to wait for the re-syncing to complete. Then I can fearlessly reboot (after issuing `update-initramfs -u` as well).

Comment: For your interest, I have also asked in the Funtoo forum about when the OS tries to assemble the Array (http://forums.funtoo.org/viewtopic.php?pid=9514#p9514).

Comment: Funtooers in the funtoo irc channel, suggested to `rc-update add mdraid boot`. It seems it kinda works. During the boot process I can see, finally, related messages. Though, again, the Array fails to be assembled. The error during the boot process reads: `/dev/md/0 is already in use.` A few lines later, `/dev/md0 can't read superblock` and in the next line `Soma local filesystem failed to mount`.

Comment: I am giving up. After a full Back Up, I will try to recreate the Array from the scratch. I wonder if I should trust the MotherBoard's hardware RAID system and let it do whatever it has to do.

Comment: Still, not able to establish a clean RAID 1 setup in Funtoo. This is really hard for me. Every time I reboot, the "system" creates two `md`s, one `md126` and one `md127`. Why?

Comment: Due to my ignorance on how to resolve this issue, I scratched the RAID idea all together. I installed ZFS and find it incredibly easy to create a "mirror" using two disks. So much to my attempts for RAID...

Comment: Closed at OP request; solved the problem a different way, and this seems fairly specific to his issue

Answer (score 2):

OK—I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong on your box, but how about a quick summary of how this is *supposed* to work, to aid in troubleshooting.

When you create an array with persistent superblocks (the quite sane default, and the way you've done it), mdadm stores various metadata on each disk. Included in that metadata is the array UUID, the array name, and the slot number. Each disk stores the same UUID and name. The slot number is different for each disk. (If you want to see the metadata, use `mdadm -E`)

There are three different ways arrays can be assembled on boot:

1. The kernel can do it. This is what the 0xFD autodetect partition type did. This method discouraged.
2. Your distro's scripts may do it as part of `udev`, using incremental assembly, passing the devices to `mdadm` as they show up. This is the newest method. When it works right, it handles all kinds of asynchronously probed devices like USB, without kluges.
3. Your distro's scripts call `mdadm --assemble --scan` after all devices are believed to have been recognized. Kluges are required for, e.g., USB (basically, a sleep to make sure the device nodes have been created). In this mode, `mdadm` checks (by default) `/proc/partitions` to find all the block devices on the system, and scans each of them for a superblock.

The distro scripts may do this in the initramfs or later. Or, sometimes, some arrays are done from initramfs (the ones required to get the root filesystem) and others later in the boot.

Regardless of how it's done, mdadm matches devices by looking at the UUID, name, and slot number. It needs to find #0 and #1 for your two-disk array. It really doesn't care which device it is (by default—you can configure it to care in mdadm.conf)

Comment: Quite some information here. Thanks. It means that I should proceed in attaching any disk without hesitation then, given all of current details about the disks and status of the Array (see also updated stuff in the "question") look healthy. Does hardware play any role? Motherboard, ability to hot-swap disks, etc.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Hardware of course plays some role. It has to support hot swap (I believe SATA inherently does, and probably SAS too). In order to actually use it, you'll want hot-swap bays. Next, your controller chip needs to properly signal swap events (modern ones pretty much all do). Finally, the kernel drivers need to support hot swap as well (most do). If all that is in place, then hot swap should work. You will need to issue the appropriate `mdadm` commands to fail/remove/add drives. I'd personally want to test that first on disks that do *not* contain important data.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to "lock" the RAID 1 Array to only work with specific disks/partitions independently from disk device names?

You should be able to use the aliases under `/dev/disk/by-*` to accomplish this. I would suggest `/dev/disk/by-id/*`, as those will directly map to information that should be readily visible on the physical disk, but any one of the directories should hold symlinks that will be useful in your scenario. Which ones to use is largely a matter of taste.

For example, on my system, /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_ST31000340NS_9QJ26FT9-part1 maps to /dev/sdb1. That is the *bus*, *model*, *serial* and *partition* number leading to the partition in question. If a drive in the array fails, you can use something like the `mdadm` command in your question to unambigiously determine which physical drive is the culprit.

> Would it be, for example, sufficient to use the Array's UUID in /etc/fstab so as to be immune against changes of the disk device names?

I'm not really familiar with MD RAID, but would that not affect only the reference to the entire array? If you are worried about /dev/md0 suddenly showing up as /dev/md1, maybe there are other ways to provide a fixed reference to the array itself?

Comment: I have thought about `/dev/disk/by-*` but, being not an expert, I'd rather ask before I try. I don't think I worry about `md0` becoming `md-`some-number, if this is possible at all. Rather, how not to loose the RAID set-up no matter if I plug-in a new internal or external disk that would show up with a device disk name already "taken" for some/all of the RAID-disks.

Comment: Quotting: _would that not affect only the reference to the entire array?_ Ehm, I guess so. So I am really after the disks that are parts of the RAID Array.